# Bidirectional BFS on a matrix in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.x, pathfinding, breadth-first-search

This code is a bidirectional BFS search. Given any two points in a matrix having 0's and 1's, I would like to find if there exists a path between them. Also note that it is forbidden to enter a cell that has a value of 0.

One note I would like to make about the code is that I have maintained a duplicate matrix to check if a particular cell has been visited by the source/destination.

Can someone please let me know if there are any discrepancies in what I have implemented and how I can improve the time efficiency of this? I am new to Python.

```
import copy



def path_exists(grid, queries):
    #iterate through queries.
    result=[]
    for (x1,y1,x2,y2) in queries:
        print "query",x1,y1,x2,y2
        if isValidIndex((x1,y1),(x2,y2),grid) != 0:
            result.append(findPath(x1,y1,x2,y2,grid))
        else:
            result.append(0)

    return result


def isValidIndex(startIndex,endIndex,grid):
    if startIndex[0] >= len(grid) or startIndex[0] < 0 or startIndex[1] >= len(grid[0]) or startIndex[1] < 0 or endIndex[0] >= len(grid) or endIndex[0] < 0 or endIndex[1] >= len(grid[0]) or endIndex[1] < 0 :
        return 0
    return 1

def findPath(x1,y1,x2,y2,grid):
    queue1=[[x1,y1]]
    queue2=[[x2,y2]]

    bool_grid = copy.deepcopy(grid)

    source_path = 0
    dest_path = 0

    while(1):
       if len(queue1) > 0:
           if find_path_from_source(queue1,grid,bool_grid,3) == 1:
               return 1

       if len(queue2) > 0:
           if find_path_from_source(queue2,grid,bool_grid,4) == 1:
               return 1

       if len(queue1) == 0 and len(queue2) == 0:
           return 0


def find_path_from_source(queue,grid,bool_grid,val):
    x=queue[0][0]
    y=queue[0][1]
    other_val = val

    if val == 3:
        other_val = 4
    else:
        other_val = 3


    if x + 1 < len(grid):
        if bool_grid[x+1][y] == other_val:
            return 1
        elif bool_grid[x+1][y] == 1:
            bool_grid[x+1][y] = val
            queue.append([x+1,y])

    if y + 1 < len(grid[0]):
        if bool_grid[x][y+1] == other_val:
            return 1
        elif bool_grid[x][y+1] == 1:
            bool_grid[x][y+1] = val
            queue.append([x,y+1])

    if x - 1 >= 0:
        if bool_grid[x - 1][y] == other_val:
            return 1
        elif bool_grid[x - 1][y] == 1:
            bool_grid[x - 1][y] = val
            queue.append([x - 1 , y])

    if y - 1 >= 0:
        if bool_grid[x][y - 1] == other_val:
            return 1
        elif bool_grid[x][y - 1] == 1:
            bool_grid[x][y - 1] = val
            queue.append([x, y - 1])

    queue.pop(0)


grid =  [[1,0,0,1,1],
         [0,1,1,1,1],
         [1,1,0,1,1],
         [0,1,1,0,1],
         [1,1,1,0,1]]

queries=((1,2,2,3),(0,0,1,1),(2,0,0,4),(5,0,2,5),(4,4,0,0),(0,4,4,4))


x = path_exists(grid,queries)

print x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `isValidIndex` handling two "indices" seems wrong. At least the condition you spell becomes too long. Besides, the condition looks somewhat inside-out. Consider

  ```
  def isValidIndex(index, grid):
      return 0 <= index[0] < len(grid) and 0 <= index[1] < len(grid[0])
  ```

  That said, AFNP principle tells that you don't really need this function at all:

  ```
      for (x1,y1,x2,y2) in queries:
          try:
              result.append(findPath(x1,y1,x2,y2,grid))
          except IndexError:
              results.append(0)
  ```
- `find_path_from_source` has an execution path which returns nothing. Here you can get away with it, but the practice is in generally dangerous and indicates sloppy coding.
- The repetitive code in `find_path_from_source` should be wrapped in the loop:

  ```
      for dx, dy in [(-1, 0), (1, 0), (0, -1), (0, 1)]:
          try:
              if bool_grid[x + dx][y + dy] == other_val:
                  return 1
              if bool_grid[x + dx][y + dy] == 1:
                  bool_grid[x + dx][y + dy] = val
                  queue.append([x + dx, y + dy])
          except IndexError:
                  pass
  ```
- The `bool_grid` name is misleading. What is `bool` about it?
- Copying a large grid *may* hurt the performance. An alternative is to compare visited cells: once they have a common element, the path is found. Implementing them as sets *may* make it quite fast. Of course, when in doubt, profile.

Comment: wouldnt the exception handling be slower than prechecking for conditions  ?

Comment: @Sujith In languages like C++ and Java exceptions are heavy, and are only used as the last resort. Not in Python. Python is designed around lightweight exceptions (in fact, even the simple things like `for` loop use them under the hood).